# In .htaccess, how do I redirect a url when a word is alone?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I have a situation where I need to create multiple redirects.

I want to redirect /blog to /food, which can be easily done by

```
Redirect 301 /blog /food
```

But then I also need to redirect /blog/example to /another-example. But because I created the former redirect, this is what ends up happening:

```
/blog/example
```

becomes

```
/food/example
```

instead of

```
/another-example
```

because it's changing /blog to /food before considering anything else.

Any help?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redirect directive matches rest of the uri and appends it to the destination. To redirect a specific uri, you need to use RedirectMatch.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/blog/?$ /food
```

Clear your browse cache before testing this.